# populating models in django using faker

Tags: python, django, orm, model, faker

[1]Why this code is not throwing an Integrity Error: Unique constraint failed.

In the population.py file:-

the line **top = add_topic()** will be called 10 times, which means it will create 10
instances of the Topic table, but it can't create 10 instances of Topic table
because the column it has is unique. So, my question is should this code not  throw a unique constraint Error? Because it's not and is running just fine. Why?

```
#models.py file

from django.db import models

# Create your models here.

class Topic(models.Model):

    top_name = models.CharField(max_length = 264,unique = True )

    def __str__(self):
        return self.top_name

class Webpage(models.Model):
    topic = models.ForeignKey(Topic, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 264, unique = True)
    url = models.URLField(unique = True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class AccessRecord(models.Model):
    name = models.ForeignKey(Webpage, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    date = models.DateTimeField()

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.date)
```

```
#population.py file

import os
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE','protwo.settings')

import django
django.setup()

import random
from first_app.models import AccessRecord,Topic,Webpage
from faker import Faker


fakegen = Faker()

topics = ['Search', 'Social', 'Marketplace', 'News', 'Games']

def add_topic():
    t = Topic.objects.get_or_create(top_name = random.choice(topics))[0]
    t.save()
    return t

def populate(N = 10):

    for entry in range(N):

        top = add_topic() 

        fake_url = fakegen.url()
        fake_date = fakegen.date()
        fake_name = fakegen.company()

        webpg = Webpage.objects.get_or_create(topic = top, url = fake_url, name = fake_name)[0]

        acc_rec = AccessRecord.objects.get_or_create(name = webpg, date = fake_date)[0]

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print('populating script')
    populate(20)
    print('populating complete!')
```

```
#populationone.py file
import os

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE','advcbv.settings')

import django
django.setup()

from basicapp.models import Students, Schools
from faker import Faker
import random

fakegen = Faker()

allschools = ['Central Academy', 'Patanjali', 'LBS', 'Dev Prayag', 'SRM', 'DPS']

def add_topic():

    fake_principal = fakegen.prefix() + fakegen.name()
    fake_location = fakegen.address()

    t = Schools.objects.get_or_create(sch_name = random.choice(allschools), principal = fake_principal, location = fake_location)[0]
    t.save()
    return t


def populate(n = 10):

    for i in range(n):

        school_obj = add_topic()

        fake_name = fakegen.name()

        fake_age = random.randint(10,16)

        student_obj = Students.objects.get_or_create(school = school_obj, stud_name = fake_name, age = fake_age)[0]

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print('populating script')
    populate(20)
    print('population complete')
```

```
#modelsone.py file

from django.db import models

# Create your models here.

class Schools(models.Model):

    sch_name = models.CharField(max_length = 256,unique = True)
    principal = models.CharField(max_length = 256)
    location = models.CharField(max_length = 256)


    def __str__(self):

        return self.name

class Students(models.Model):

    stud_name = models.CharField(max_length = 256)
    school = models.ForeignKey(Schools, on_delete = models.CASCADE,related_name='related_students')
    age = models.PositiveIntegerField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

[here is the error thrown by populateone.py]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/toGYp.png

Comment: `get_or_create` creates a new instance when no corresponding object exists, else it just fetches the existing object

Comment: Ok, I am adding new code now which throws that error could you please clarify why is this happening?

Answer (score 1):

If top_name has `Unique=True`, then this field must be unique throughout the table.

But error is not showing up because of `get_or_create`. What `get_or_create` does here is that it returns a **tuple i.e. (object, created)**. First one is an instance of the model you are trying to **get** and the second is a flag to tell if the instance was created or not. **True** means the instance was created by the `get_or_create` method and **False** means it was retrieved from the database.

The `get_or_create` will create an instance if doesn't exist. Else it would simply update the existing instance.

Comment: @prakhar kesarwani I have seen your edit **modelsone.py throwing error with respect to populationone.py** Right ? Be more specific with error and if you can share error it'd be good.

Comment: Yes, you are right sir. My question is why populateone.py file is throwing an error when it is almost same as the populate.py file. I have also included the error file now. Please check the link.